# Different redirection for two login forms

Tags: magento-1.9, redirect

I have same login form of magento in two different phtml pages(one is default login page and other is my custom phtml page but the login code is same since i copied from default login page). Now what I want is when user is logging with default login page redirection is to dashboard(which is by default) and when user is logging with my custom login form page, I want him to redirected to other page other than the dashboard.Is it possible?If yes then please elaborate how?

Comment: yes it is possible

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### [Edited:]

**In order to full fill your requirement, need to use Event/Observer.**

- First create a custom input hidden field (custom_redirect) at custom
  phtml
     Input this field: **`<input name="custom_redirect" type="hidden" value="1"/>`**
- **`Then using customer_login event for redirect to custom  page on basic
  of custom_redirect.`**

At event fire an observer which redirect to your`custom url page 
on basic of`  **custom_redirect** input value using **magento FrontController 
prediction action**

`Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getResponse()->setRedirect("YOUR_URL");`

**config.xml:**

```
 <frontend>
        <events>
            <customer_login>
                <observers>
                    <redirect_to_anthor_page>
                        <class>StackExchange_Magento90351_Model_Observer</class>
                        <method>redirectNotLogged</method>
                    </redirect_to_anthor_page>
                </observers>
            </customer_login>
        </events>
    </frontend>
```

**Observer code:**

> ```
> <?php
>
> /*
>  * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
>  * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
>  * and open the template in the editor.
>  */
>
> /**
>  * Description of Observer
>  *
>  * @author work
>  */
> class StackExchange_Magento90351_Model_Observer {
>     //put your code here
>  public function redirectNotLogged(Varien_Event_Observer $observer){
>      if(Mage::app()->getRequest()->getParam('custom_redirect')==1):
>         Mage::app()->getResponse()->setRedirect(Mage::getUrl('affiliate/index/d‌ashboard'))
>             ->sendResponse();
>         exit;
>        endif; 
>      } 
>
> }
> ```

Comment: I tried to implement your method but when I am adding events to config.xml
my custom form page showing 404

Comment: after fixing  1 spelling mistake 404 gone but  it's not redirecting to my page instead goin to dashboard

Comment: i tried to use die() and found that is not entering if condition

Comment: please change  to Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getResponse()->setRedirect("YOUR_URL");

Comment: yes i have already done but its not entering the if condition.

Comment: please check the update]

Comment: still its redirecting to customer/account/

Comment: `code`
 die("hellppp");
  /* here check and redirect to specific page */
if(Mage::app()->getRequest()->getParam('custom_redirect') ==1){
    die("hellppp2");
       Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getResponse()->setRedirect("affiliate/index/dashboard/");
         exit();
}else{
   die('help3');
}

it's never satisfying the condition. it'sprinting help and hlp 3 never help 2

here's the html input type
<input type="hidden" name="custom_redirect" id="custom_redirect" value="" />

Comment: code is tested.. Now it working

Comment: thnx a lot for helping me out !!